# AHK Disable Script A when Script B is Executed

Tags: autohotkey

hi again my script is almost complete but there is problem in executing hotkeys

Problem : when i hit Alt + Space it is conflicting with Space .. they are overlaping each other or executing both hotkey which makes custom modifier keys unstable or not working as intented

here is the code:

```
space::
send {shift down}{MButton down}
KeyWait, space
send {shift up}{Mbutton up}
return

!space::
send {Mbutton down}
KeyWait, space
keywait, alt
send {Mbutton Up}
return


#if, GetKeyState("MButton")
    Lbutton::
    RButton::
    return
#if
```

**i want to add a rule if *alt + space* keycombo is held down this hotkey will not work**

meaning i want to disable Script A if Script B is executed

Script A ::

```
space::
    send {shift down}{MButton down}
    KeyWait, space
    send {shift up}{Mbutton up}
    return
```

Script B ::

```
  !space::
    send {Mbutton down}
    KeyWait, space
    keywait, alt
    send {Mbutton Up}
    return
```

thank you in advance

Comment: 1) try `sendplay` instead of `send` 2) try prefixing key labels: `$space::` and `$!space::` 3) try both methods

Comment: thank you for reply but i really have no idea about sendplay and keylabels .. im still new at auto hotkey

Comment: Currently you're using `send`, I've suggested using `sendplay` and adding `$` before the key labels exactly as I've shown. Also you may want to read the official [tutorial](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `space::` part in `#If, !GetKeyState("Alt")`

```
!space::
send {Mbutton down}
KeyWait, space
keywait, alt
send {Mbutton Up}
return


#if, !GetKeyState("Alt")

space::
send {shift down}{MButton down}
KeyWait, space
send {shift up}{Mbutton up}
return

#if, GetKeyState("MButton")
    Lbutton::
    RButton::
    return
#if
```

Comment: thank you it was similar format code that someone gave me answers from AHK forum

Answer (score 0):

```
space::
Hotkey_Alt_Space = 0    ; disabled
send {shift down}{MButton down}
KeyWait, space
send {shift up}{Mbutton up}
Hotkey_Alt_Space = 1
return

!space::
If (Hotkey_Alt_Space != 0)  ; enabled
{
send {Mbutton down}
KeyWait, space
keywait, alt
send {Mbutton Up}
}
return
```

i was help by someone at AHK forum thank you for time the problem is solve i am able to customize my rotate and pan navigation at sketchup